# JUnit testing spring-integration configuration

Tags: java, junit, spring-integration

Does anyone know of a bootstrap or rather reference project for a `spring-integration`  project for `JUnit` testing?

The goal is to ensure that the spring-integration configuration are correct and remains correct via `JUnit` instead of finding out much later.

Typically one would need to test out things like routers, splitters, mock queues etc.

Any such basic project anyone already created will be of help instead of reinventing one myself.

Answer (score 0):

use this link I had used it for spring integration.

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/tree/master/basic/testing-examples